# O que significa "meu cantinho está um brinco"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

O que quer dizer **meu cantinho está um brinco**?

> Será que quer dizer **um lugar está bom**?

> Exemplo: Eu limpei toda a minha casa hoje. Meu cantinho está um brinco!
> Meu carro está um brinco! está muito limpo.

Comment: Majid, converti a minha resposta para português. Nem reparei que tinhas perguntado em português... :) Fazes boas perguntas, espero que a tua aprendizagem continue bem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A expressão "X está um brinco" significa que algo está muito bem feito, ou muito bonito ou limpo.

Isto segue a 4ª entrada na [definição no dicionário Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/brinco):

> 4. Aquilo que é *muito bonito ou muito limpo* (ex.: a casa ficou um brinco).

(Consultado em 2021-02-09, https://dicionario.priberam.org/brinco)

O dicionário Aulete tem [entradas ainda mais explícitas](https://www.aulete.com.br/brinco) sobre isto:

> (brin.co) sm.
>
> 1. Enfeite que se usa no lobo das orelhas
> 2. P.ext. Qualquer enfeite ou adorno
> 3. Fig. P.ext. **Coisa ou pessoa bonita, bem apresentada, elegante, fina etc.**: Fui visitar o novo apartgamento dele, que brinco!: Caprichou na indumentária, estava um brinco.
> 4. (...)
>
> Um brinco
>
> 1. Limpo, cuidado, arrumado, com excelente aspecto etc.: A casa está um brinco.

https://www.aulete.com.br/brinco

Comment: Já agora, tens *cantinho* no [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/cantinho/) e [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/cantinho) com o significado geral relevante; na pergunta é um caso particular, casa ou, menos provavelmente, lugar de trabalho.

Comment: Meu carro está um brinco!